# $k\geq n+1$ convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: convex-geometry

Assume that $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_{k}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ are $k$ convex sets and $k\geq n+1$. Is it true that there exist two distinct points $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^k$ such that $$
\gamma_{11}A_1+\gamma_{12}A_2+\dots+\gamma_{1{k}}A_k=\gamma_{21}A_1+\gamma_{22}A_2+\dots+\gamma_{2{k}}A_k \quad?
$$

Note that this claim holds when $A_i$ are point-sets. In this case, I may define a $n\times k$-matrix $$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 & \dots & A_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and since $k>n$ there exist $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ such that $A\gamma_1=A\gamma_2$. It is also not hard to show that these $\gamma_i$ can be chosen from $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^k$.

I thought some version of Helly's theorem should apply here, but I cannot see how.

Comment: Can you define what that equality means?   $\quad$ I suspect that in $ n = 1$, $[0, 1 ]$ and $ [ 1, 2 ]$ are counter examples.

Comment: @CalvinLin The equality is the equality of sets. I think your example is indeed a counter-example. Thanks!